# Failed to load resource, Javascript, HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, game-engine

I'm trying to get my Sprite to show up because I'm making a game using Javascript with HTML5. This has worked for me before a while back, but now then it stopped working, so I decided to rewrite the script again -- it still doesn't work. Not sure what the problem is, but here's the Javascript code, and then, the HTML code. Thanks! Also - I'm using Chrome. And the Sprite has showed up in the Chrome internet browser before.

The Javascript Code:

```
var canvasBg = document.getElementById('canvasBg');
var ctxBg = canvasBg.getContext('2d');
var clearCanvasBtn = document.getElementById('clearCanvasBtn');
clearCanvasBtn.addEventListener('click',clearCanvas,false);

var gameWidth = canvasBg.width;
var gameHeight = canvasBg.height;

var imgSprite = new Image();
imgSprite.src = 'sprite.png';
imgSprite.addEventListener('load',drawBg,false);

function drawBg() {
var srcX = 0;
var srcY = 0;
var drawX = 0;
var drawY = 0;
ctxBg.drawImage(imgSprite,srcX,scrY,gameWidth,gameHeight,drawX,drawY,gameWidth,game    Height); 

}
function clearCanvas() {
ctxBg.clearRect(0,800,500); 
}`
```

HTML code...:

`
    
    
    
    Youtube HTML5 Game Dev Tutorial

```
<button id="clearCanvasBtn" type="button">Clear Canvas</button>
<canvas id="canvasBg" width="800px" height="500px"                           style="display:block;background:#ffffff;margin:100px auto 0px;"></canvas>;
<script src="game tester.js"></script>
```

`

Comment: Well this could be because the .png is not in the folder relative to the site. Or there is also a space in between "game tester.js" as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what "stopped working" means, but...

**There is a new bug in Chrome when creating Image objects**

So, if your code worked fine before but fails after a Chrome update, try this:

```
// instead of new Image()
var imgSprite = document.createElement("img");
```